# Error with async js function and logging

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have this function with callbacks:

```
function getStorageByKey(key, callback) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function(obj, callback) {
    var error = chrome.runtime.lastError;
       if (error) {
           console.error(error);
       }
  callback(obj)
  });
}
```

I'm trying to log it's output like this:

```
  getStorageByKey('hidden_threads', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
  });
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Error in response to storage.get: TypeError: callback is not a function
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://nnaebcfbeghbbdkcgdicmlagdblheccm/content.js:37:3)
    at getStorageByKey (chrome-extension://nnaebcfbeghbbdkcgdicmlagdblheccm/content.js:32:23)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://nnaebcfbeghbbdkcgdicmlagdblheccm/content.js:8:3)
    at j (chrome-extension://nnaebcfbeghbbdkcgdicmlagdblheccm/jquery.min.js:2:29999)
    at k (chrome-extension://nnaebcfbeghbbdkcgdicmlagdblheccm/jquery.min.js:2:30313)
```

Comment: @Vasan this worked! if you want to write it up as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: Done, I've made it into an answer! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`function(obj, callback)` - This function is invoked by `chrome.storage.sync.get` once it finishes its own processing. So the second `callback` parameter would be passed by `chrome.storage.sync.get` (if at all) and the `callback` variable you've declared outside this function will be ignored.

So remove the `callback` parameter to this function, which will make it to use the `callback` variable from outside scope.